# Regular Expressions retrieve text between words with re-occurring pattern

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I have the following Literal Text

> "value":"1001174227","fieldLabel":"A field"},{"value":"THE VALUE I NEED","fieldLabel":"Period"}

My goal was to use regular expressions to extract the string

```
THE VALUE I NEED
```

I attempted to match using the regular expression using the standard start and end identifiers by pulling the text in the middle (see my regex below) but it pulls out the whole string. I think this is because of the reoccurring text **value**.

```
\"value\":\"(.*)\",\"fieldLabel\":\"Period\"
```

Comment: `\"value\":\"(.*?)\",\"fieldLabel\":\"Period\"`

Comment: It looks like you're trying to some kind of standard data interchange format like JSON.  Is there not a library that's already been written, tested and debugged that can do it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture non-quotes:

```
value\":\"([^\"]*)\",\"fieldLabel\":\"Period\"
```

This forces the only match to be the `value` immediately preceding your target.

The expression `[^"]` means "any char not a quote", thus restricting the capturing match to only chars between quotes.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/bm3P3aViti) showing target input captured as group 1.

Using a reluctant quantifier `.*?` won't work, because the first `value` can still match.

Comment: @peter I've added an explanation to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to simplify it right down to:

```
"([^"]*)","fieldLabel":"Period"
```

Depending on the rest of your code, you may or may not need to replace `"` with `\"`. For example, could you use single quotes (`'`) to define the regex string, and thereby avoid all the ugly backslashes?

Comment: This will pull out the text "THE VALUE I NEED","fieldLabel":"Period"}

Comment: Yes, and `THE VALUE I NEED` is stored in a capture group.

Comment: It's carries on with the entire ending though ?

Comment: Capture groups are stored into variables. A quick google tells me that in `objective-c`, you can access the capture group via `$1`. I can't really provide much more code without knowing what you want to *do* with the captured text, however!

Comment: Also notice that the accepted answer above uses the same method of a capture group.